# Capture audio stream from Xtion pro with OpenNI2?

Tags: audio, openni, recorder, asus-xtion

Dose any one try to captured the ***audio stream*** using ***OpenNI2*** library from ***Xtion pro***??

I searched the Internet and found the audio API in OpenNI2 source code. [Audio API](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2/blob/master/Source/Tools/NiViewer/Audio.h)

It seems that it only can "Play" the audio but capture audio stream.

And it doesn't demonstrate how to use those API.

Is there any ***example code*** which recorded the audio stream using OpenNI2 from Xtion pro?

BTW, my OpenNI version is 2.2.0.33.

Thanks anyone's help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I surveyed so much information, I found that OpenNI2 didn't support the audio stream anymore. Hence, someone suggest me to use another library to capture audio stream from Xtion Pro.

Now, I'm using the [***PortAudio***](http://portaudio.com/) to deal with the audio stream. It's quit powerful tool and easy to use.

Moreover, it's cross-platform library which support Windows, Mac OS, and Unix using C/C++, and the [*Documentation*](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/index.html) is clear and the example code is understandable.

So, if some newbies like me want to use Xtion Pro to capture audio stream, I will recommend this library.

Any other suggestions are very welcome : )